# How do I Balance Multiple Service Contracts with Duplicate Structures

Tags: c#, web-services

My current task requires me to use a set of web service calls to a 3rd party vendor in order to retrieve and update information.

The objects used in these calls - namely the response from a **get** and the object passed to (and received from) an **update** - are identical except for the a prefix tacked on to the objects.

For example, a call to the **get** method may return an object like so (*the actual structure may be a dozen levels deep and have a mix of properties/collections*):

```
<getFooResponse>
    <getFooResponsePropertyA>1</getFooResponsePropertyA>
    <getFooResponsePropertyB>2</getFooResponsePropertyB>
    <getFooResponsePropertyC>3</getFooResponsePropertyC>
</getFooResponse>
```

and a call to the **update** method may take an object that looks similar:

```
<updateFooRequest>
    <updateFooRequestPropertyA>4</updateFooRequestPropertyA>
    <updateFooRequestPropertyB>5</updateFooRequestPropertyB>
    <updateFooRequestPropertyC>6</updateFooRequestPropertyC>
</updateFooRequest>
```

and return a third similar object:

```
<updateFooResponse>
    <updateFooResponsePropertyA>4</updateFooResponsePropertyA>
    <updateFooResponsePropertyB>5</updateFooResponsePropertyB>
    <updateFooResponsePropertyC>6</updateFooResponsePropertyC>
</updateFooResponse>
```

Using C#, service references are easily added to my project and the concretions of the classes needed to call the API or parse a response are generated for me.

My problem lies in the fact that 3 classes are automatically generated with a nearly identical structure.

Thus I have (automatically generated):

- get **Foo** Response
- update **Foo** Request
- update **Foo** Response

the only difference being the prefix/suffix.

I really only care about the **Foo** object (as it's ~identical in all 3 scenarios).

It's a quite common scenario to do the following

- get a response from the 3rd party system
- modify the response slightly
- push the modified response back up to the 3rd party system (after converting it from a **getFooResponse** to an **updateFooRequest**)

The problem lies in the sheer amount of code necessary to map from one version of the object to another. I realize I can do this with reflection, but it's not as clear as I'd like and I'm not sure how maintainable it is for one who comes after me.

Do I have any options other than writing code that hard-codes mappings between different flavors of the objects?

Comment: There are tools that can convert between the types for you, like [Automaper](http://automapper.org/).

Comment: Does the tool auto generate the objects with the `partial` keyword? If so, just add the partial to P. Roe's answer and you likely have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're deserializing from the xml response and serializing from the objects themselves here is a model that may work for you.

```
public abstract class FooMessage
{
      [XmlIgnore]
      string A { get; set; }
      [XmlIgnore]
      string B { get; set; }
      [XmlIgnore]
      string C { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateFooRequest : FooMessage
{
      public string UpdateFooRequestPropertyA { get { return this.A;} set { this.A = value;} }
      public string UpdateFooRequestPropertyB { get { return this.B;} set { this.B = value;} }
      public string UpdateFooRequestPropertyC { get { return this.A;} set { this.C = value;} }
}

public class UpdateFooResponse : FooMessage
{
      public string UpdateFooResponsePropertyA { get { return this.A;} set { this.A = value;} }
      public string UpdateFooResponsePropertyB { get { return this.B;} set { this.B = value;} }
      public string UpdateFooResponsePropertyC { get { return this.A;} set { this.C = value;} }
}

// usage
var myMessage = new FooMessage{ A="TestA", B="TestB", C="TestC" };

var myUpdateMessage = myMessage as UpdateFooRequest;
if(myUpdateMessage != null)
{
      var messageString = ConvertToXml(myUpdateMessage);
      SendMessage(messageString);
}
```

This isn't much better than just doing the mapping code however doing it this way would easily allow for some code generation. I'm also assuming that you want to serialize/deserialize straight to/from the object/message themselves.